# UTF-8 should be using CHAR or NCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server, character-encoding

If I'm using utf-8 encoding for a character set that would use the character set for non-Cyrillic european languages, can I use varchar/char, or should I use nvarchar/nchar?

is there a huge sql processing time penalty for using nvarchar?

Comment: what server are you using - MS SQL?

Comment: Do select @@version and find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

internal data representation for nvarchar is UTF-16. AFAIK you cannot change it, so you better use nvarchar for parameters.

Answer (score 2):

MSSQL doesn't support UTF-8 natively, so use nchar.
You must make sure that your code is consistent about the character sets it inserts as that means the RDBMS won't. MSSQL *does* support UTF-16, so you might consider using that charset for your application instead.